# Track/View new incoming links with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

Is there a way to track **new incoming links** to my website?

When I visit "*Traffic Sources -> Referring Sites*" in my Google Analytics account I have a list with 5,391 sites so its quiet hard to discover new sites which link to me. Is there a way to just show new links?

How do you differ between new and old incoming links?

**Update:**
I might have found a solution: http://tumblr.goloso.cl/post/1185978899/new-referrals-links-as-google-analytics-goals

I will test it and report if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the **Google Analytics way didn't work** for me(I might have messed up the code a bit, still, I tried a few things to fix it without solving the problem).

**To solve my problem I build my own little tracker**. Every referrer which is not already in the database will be saved. It's not perfect and I might have to improve a few things (doen't save referrers from search engines, etc.) but its working the way I wanted it.

**Nice addition**: I can click on the links directly while in Google Analytics I had to first click on the "domain" to see the whole url path and click on that.

Answer (score 0):

On that same screen, above the graph on the right, look for Advanced Segments. Click the drop-down widget next to it.  In the resulting box, there's a "Default Segments" column, with a "New Visitors" Option. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: New visitors isn't really what I'm looking for, more like new referrals. I'm looking for an option that shows me new referrals, which aren't already tracked. For example Link A links to my site and the first week visitors are coming to my site with that link, Link A is shown as "new". As soon as one week has passed and visitors come to my site over Link A, this link is not "new" anymore.

Comment: maybe if every referral in Google Analytics had a "first tracked date" I could order the list and see new incoming links. Is there something like that?